# Updating Data on Logout in Java EE web application

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee

I have a web application built using jsp/servlets.The web application session is set to timeout after say 5 mins of inactivity by the user which is set in web.xml.

Now i want to update some details just before this session timeout occurs pertaining to a user whose session is getting timed out.

Say a user has logged in and incouse of time the user chooses to stay inactive in this situation i need to update some information for the user whose session is being timed out.

How do i achieve the same.

```
package com.student.track;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionEvent; 
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener; 

public class sessionInfo implements HttpSessionListener {


    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) { 

    } 
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) { 

        String query = "insert into SessionInfo values(?)";
        try
        {
        runQuery(query);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } 

    public static void runQuery(String query)  throws Exception

    {
        Connection conn=null;
        int result=0;
        try
        {
            conn = getConnection();
            PreparedStatement stat=null;
            stat = conn.prepareStatement(query); 
            stat.setString(1,"first");
            result = stat.executeUpdate(query);
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            try 
            {
                conn.close();
            } 
            catch (SQLException e) 
            {
                throw e;
            }
        }

    }

    public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException, IOException, Exception
    {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("database.properties");
        props.load(in);
        in.close();

        String drivers = props.getProperty("dbcb.jdbcDriver");
        try
        {
            Class.forName(drivers);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }

        if (drivers != null)
            System.setProperty("jdbc.drivers", drivers);

            String url = props.getProperty("dbcb.jdbcURL");
            String username = props.getProperty("dbcb.dbUser");
            String password = props.getProperty("dbcb.dbPassword");
            return DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
    }


    }
```

And web.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.2//EN" "http://java.sun.com/j2ee/dtds/web-app_2_2.dtd">
<web-app>
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>InitServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.student.track.InitServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>InitServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/InitServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <taglib>
    <taglib-uri>/orataglib</taglib-uri>
    <taglib-location>tlds/orataglib_1_0_2.tld</taglib-location>
  </taglib>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <resource-ref>
 <description>Sybase Datasource example</description>
 <res-ref-name>jdbc/mysybase</res-ref-name>
 <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
 <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>

<listener> 
<description>sessionListener</description> 
<listener-class> com.student.track.sessionInfo </listener-class> 
</listener>  
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fairly easy, implement a [HttpSessionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html). The container will trigger [`sessionDestroyed()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html#sessionDestroyed%28javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionEvent%29) if it decides to remove a session from its cache.

Example:

```
@WebListener /* or reister it in web.xml */
public final class MySessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {

    @Override
    public void sessionCreated(final HttpSessionEvent se) { }

    @Override
    public void sessionDestroyed(final HttpSessionEvent se) {

        // obtain HTTP session
        HttpSession session = se.getSession();

        /* as you cannot retrieve the user ID from the
         * HTTP session, getRemoteUser() is not available, you must
         * read the user ID from a custom parameter
         */
        String user = (String) session.getAttribute("myCustomAttribute");

        // work with it

    }

}
```

Update. To specify the listener in web.xml add the following tags to web.xml:

```
<listener>
  <listener-class>com.test.MySessionListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Comment: Could you give a sample for the same.And where do i do these setting for achieveing the same.

Comment: I linked the wrong class, of course it is HttpSessionListener. Will add an example

Comment: Thanks for the sample.How and where do i add this code so that it gets triggered on logout.What is the procedure for the same.

Comment: Just create a class in your project, same as for servlets. If you add the `@WebListener` annotation, the container should recognize your class and automatically call the corresponding methods. Of course this only works if your logout functionality really destroys the session. I'd add some log statements to the methods, so you can see when they actually get triggered.

Comment: Now do i have to update in the web.xml and code this class. Or perform either one of them.

Comment: Just one of them. I recommend to try both approaches if you're not experienced with those web container features.

Comment: Thanks will try and get back if i face any issues.

Comment: Updated the code above but not working.Please suggest to correct the same.

Comment: The database is not getting updated at all when i logout the session.Here in sessionDestroyed() i try to insert a value in database which is not happening.Have i missed something in the code.

Comment: I'm doubtful that  session invalidation is not causing the sessionInfo class to be run.

Comment: You should start by including trace messages using the logging framework of your choice. First check if the method is called at all (add a trace to the constructor of your listener as well, so you can see if the container really recognizes it).

Comment: I do not know. The question is whether the listener does start or not, please check this, add some log methods (or just System.out.println)...

Comment: Code is working now.I have a question though.After the session is destroyed the sessionDestroyed() method is called.I this method how can we create a session object and retreive a session attribute if its already destroyed.Isn't all the session data destroyed when this method gets called.

Comment: sessionDestroyed should be called before it's actually destroyed. From the docs => Receives notification that a session is about to be invalidated

Comment: So even if i do a session invalidation in a jsp the sessionDestroyed() is executed first and the session is actually destroyed.Does it happen this way.

Comment: sessionDestroyed should be called before the container destroys it. Is that what you meant?